# LibreOffice Writer — a way to protect a shape from deleting

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

Is there a way to protect (to lock) a shape not just from resizing or moving but from deleting too? The shape should be visible, but not movable, resizable or deletable.

[image: postcard template]

I need something like Object ⟶ Lock from InDesign to "lock" the postcard shape on the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your shape in a frame, and protect the content of the frame.

Of course, this will only protect the frame (and its content) from accidentally deletion - there is no "password protected" option.

Does this help?

Comment: No, sorry, not really.